# Are these questions about resistances duplicates of each other?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

There are three related questions that link to each other and have similar answers:

- [How does Ancestral Protectors' resistance work against multiple damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130331)
- [Does a rogue's Uncanny Dodge halve each type of damage individually or the total?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130311)
- [Multiple Damage Resistance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108173)

They each (effectively) ask how damage resistance should be applied when something deals multiple damage types. **Should these questions be marked as duplicates?**
Some things to consider in choosing a potential duplicate: the third question in the oldest, its answer has the most upvotes; the second has the most views; the first and second were actually asked on the same day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

While they ultimately end up being best answered by explaining damage resistance by type they are all distinct questions asking about distinct instances in the case of the first 2 and in general in the case of the latter. As such none are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Fair point, I will still leave the core of the answer, the questions themselves are are at their heart asking "how does feature x work?" its just that the specific questions are focusing on a class specific feature that interacts with the core rules the 3rd general question is about.

Comment: While they may all have related or identical answers, they are distinct questions because they are specifically about certain class abilities from different classes. And the ones about those classes don't generalize at all in title or body.

Comment: I agree - in particular, #1 is aware of #3 but has a question about the distinction between the features: "If said creature deals multiple types of damage in one attack - if a creature is resistant to all of those forms of damage, this answer states that each damage type is halved before damage is totaled. However, Ancestral Protectors does not give resistance to each type of damage dealt by the attack - it gives resistance to the attack itself. When calculating the damage dealt, would you still calculate it per the linked answer, or would you add it all, and then apply resistance?"

Comment: @V2Blast That argument in your comment really sold it for me

Comment: Yes, questions are duplicates when they are the same question, not when the generate the same answers. "What measurement is 12 inches?" and "What's at the end of your leg?" are different questions with the same answer.